# Can't bind WHERE part in a SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, crystal-reports

When you try to create this proc on MS SQL Server 2008 and try to bind a report (Crystal or SQL Server reporting) you can't get any parameter from the report. I don't get any errors. I just see the proc name and no column under it to get any data from it. Please help

```
create proc getdata 
@where as nvarchar (max)
as
declare @sql as varchar(max)
set @sql='select cp.address,
(case when cp.male =1 then ''Male'' 
      when cp.female =1 then ''Female'' 
      else null end ) AS "Gender" 
from consumer_premium cp where '+ @where
exec(@sql);
```

@where example execution

```
getdata 'male=1'
```

thats the table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Consumer_Premium](
    [Address] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Male] [bit] NULL,
    [Female] [bit] NULL)
```

please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [sql query problem when reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520506/sql-query-problem-when-reporting)

Comment: Syntax Error: Can't convert "u" to anything meaningful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible option that you can try if you are using `SSRS 2008`. Following example was created using SSRS 2008 based on the data provided in the question.

1. Create a table named `dbo.Consumer_Premium` and stored procedure named `dbo.GetData` using the scripts provided under SQL Scripts section. Populate the table with data as shown in screenshot #**1**.
2. Create an SSRS report named `BindWhere.rdl` as shown in screenshot #**2**.
3. Create a report parameter named `Gender` with settings as shown in screenshots #**3** - #**5**.
4. Configure the report data source as shown in screenshots #**6** - #**8**.
5. Screenshot #**9** shows default report execution with parameter `Gender` set to value **Male**.
6. Screenshot #**10** shows default report execution when the parameter `Gender` value is changed to **Female**. You need to click on the View Report button to refresh the data.

Hope that helps.

**SQL Scripts:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Consumer_Premium](
    [Address] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Male] [bit] NULL,
    [Female] [bit] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE getdata 
(
    @where AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
)   
AS
    DECLARE @sql AS VARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @sql='select cp.address,
    (case when cp.male =1 then ''Male'' 
          when cp.female =1 then ''Female'' 
          else null end ) AS "Gender" 
    from consumer_premium cp where '+ @where
    EXEC(@sql);
GO
```

**Screenshot #1:**

[image: 1]

**Screenshot #2:**

[image: 2]

**Screenshot #3:**

[image: 3]

**Screenshot #4:**

[image: 4]

**Screenshot #5:**

[image: 5]

**Screenshot #6:**

[image: 6]

**Screenshot #7:**

[image: 7]

**Screenshot #8:**

[image: 8]

**Screenshot #9:**

[image: 9]

**Screenshot #10:**

[image: 10]